# Django app os.getcwd() shows apache serverRoot

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have a working django app deployed on `apache using mod_wsgi`. The app works fine.

In my app views.py,i import a module(`"mymodule.py"`) that is at the root of the django project.

Now,when i import the module and run os.getcwd() within a function in the module,I get the serverRoot of Apache as the output(`"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.4"`). I want it to be the root of my django project.

I get the desired output(`"F:\DjangoPro\mysite"`) while running the project using runserver webserver provided with django.

My docroot in httpd.conf is set at

```
DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.4/htdocs"
```

and the server root is set at

```
ServerRoot "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.4"
```

The wsgi config is as follows-

```
#static portion
Alias /static/ F:/DjangoPro/mysite/home/static/
<Directory "F:/DjangoPro/mysite/home/static">
Require all granted
</Directory>

### Refers to the location of the wsgi file inside the project.
WSGIScriptAlias / F:/DjangoPro/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath F:/DjangoPro/mysite

<Directory F:/DjangoPro/mysite/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

The home/views.py file is as follows-

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from django.shortcuts import render
import time

from mymodule import *


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse(myfunc())
```

The mymodule.py file is as follows-

```
import os
def myfunc():
    return os.getcwd()
```

My project structure is this

```
F:
--DjangoPro
    -- mysite
        --home
            -- __init__.py
            -- admin.py
            -- models.py
            -- urls.py
            -- views.py         
        -- mysite
            -- __init__.py
            -- settings.py
            -- urls.py
            -- wsgi.py
        -- manage.py
        -- mymodule.py
```

What could be the mistake?

Comment: there is no mistake. that seems to be the current working directory. i have never tried it with django, apache and `mod_wsgi`  but you could give `os.path.dirname(__file__)` a try.

Comment: ya thats the workaround i have been using for now but was wondering if there is any direct solution to it or if i have made a mistake.

Comment: that is the only reliable way i know to get the path of a project in the filesystem. i would not call it a workaround. but i'm looking forward to see if there are answers with other solutions.

Comment: Will still wait and watch if someone comes up with a solution or better workaround.